# Persistant cookie does not persist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a cookie I create:

```
   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(e.EmployeID.ToString(), true);
```

With this I would expect to stay logged in until I explicitly sign out but after 30 or so minutes, I have to sign back in.

Here is my auth class:

```
    public static class Authorization
    {
        public static bool Login(string username, string password, bool persist)
        {
            Employee e = ResourceManager.GetEmployeeByEmail(username);

            if (e == null || !ResourceManager.VerifyEmployeePassword(e.EmployeID, password))
            {
                return false;
            }

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(e.EmployeID.ToString(), persist);
            return true;
        }

        public static void Logout()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        }

        public static string GetUserId()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        }

        public static string GetUsername()
        {
            return GetEmployee().EmployeEmail;
        }

        public static bool IsAuthenticated()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }

        public static Employee GetEmployee()
        {
            int id = 0;
            int.TryParse(GetUserId(), out id);
            return ResourceManager.GetEmployee(id);
        }

        public static bool IsAdministrator()
        {
            if (!IsAuthenticated())
            {
                return false;
            }

            Employee e = GetEmployee();

            if (e != null)
            {
                return SecurityManager.IsEmployeeAdmin((e.EmployeID));
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong?

```
I have this in my web config:
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default timeout value for the auth cookie is 30 mins *unless otherwise specified*.

Since you claim to be getting logged out after 30 minutes it would suggest to me that you have *not* specified otherwise.

To do this, you must set the `timeout` property of the `<form />` element within your web.config file.

For example: -

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: I am not using forms authenication for the login page... is there just some way I can elongate my session cookie?

Comment: Then don't specify a `loginUrl`, e.g. `<forms timeout="2800" />`. Consider reading [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/08/430011.aspx) though it references asp.net 2.0, it is still relevant